# C# - Large collection storage

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I'm currently facing a head-scratching problem, I am working with a large data set (when I say large, I mean billions of rows of data) and I am caught between speed and scalability.

I can store the billions of rows of data in the database, but my application needs to constantly check whether a new row of data exists in the dataset, if not, insert it, otherwise, retrieve it.

If I were to use a database solution, I estimate each call to the database to retrieve a row of data to be 10ms (optimistic estimate), I need to retrieve about 800k records for each file that I process in my application, that means `(10ms x 800k = 2.22 hours)` per file to process. That timespan is too long to analyse and process 1 file, considering the amount of time required to retrieve a row of data from the database will increase when the database grow to billions and billions of rows.

I have also thought of storing a `List` or `HashSet` in the local memory to compare and retrieve, but it is not going to work out as I will not be able to store billions of records (objects) in the memory.

Pls advice on what I should do for my situation.

Edit: Oh ya, I forgotten to state that I have already implemented a semi-cache, once a record is retrieved, it will be cached in the memory, so if the same record needs to be retrieved again, it will be retrieved from the memory instead, but I face the same problem, I will reach a point in time where the memory can no longer fit any more cached data.

Comment: Is there any way you can reasonably determine which rows are likely to be needed for retrieval, e.g. most recent, i.e. implement a partial caching capability?

Comment: Oh ya, I forgotten to state that I have already implemented a semi-cache, once a record is retrieved, it will be cached in the memory, so if the same record needs to be retrieved again, it will be retrieved from the memory instead, but I face the same problem, I will reach a point in time where the memory can no longer fit any more cached data.

Comment: Using a HASH to compare each file you create , associate files with hash code so you need to compare HASH not FILE ?

Comment: Memory? Like the 1.5tb you can put into a modern server? They can not hold that?

Comment: Try Dictionary instead of HashSet or List. If you have many files, and their contents are independant from the others, you can parallel processes them. Another thing is, do not insert rows to db, you can set a threshold and when it is reached then do a Bulk Insert and then free that memory.

Comment: How the data set is related to files? It isn't clear.

Comment: @TomTom more like the 8gb RAM in my PC.

@hazimdikenli yes, I am already using a Dictionary to make retrieval of data faster using a `key`, but I am sure there is also a limit of how much I can hold in the Dictionary

@Dennis The data set is a list of string permutations of the file content.

Comment: @Dan: so, assuming, that there's one-to-one relation between line in the file and record in the data set, if the record, matching the line isn't in data set, then you must insert it. But when you must retrieve records from data set? What is the criteria?

Comment: @Dennis: actually the record retrieval is part of another module of the application that requires the entity ID in the database, thus, I have to retrieve it with the "text" (`SELECT Id FROM Data WHERE Text = 'Hello world'`). You might be thinking about getting the entity identity when inserting it, but I use BULK INSERT, which doesn't return the entity identity.

Comment: If your file is not that BIG , make a new file (Assuming only strings) for each permutation and get HASH for each of them. Store only original file and associated HASH [of the permutations] .. Compare HASH when you need to compare.. So your new comparison is with HASH

Comment: @KCdod say I follow your recommendation, and use a hash instead, it comes back to my question, should I store it in the database or in the memory? I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: HASH is small in size (MD5-128 bit = 16 bytes) . So 800K per file means 12.8 Mb per one file's permutation HASH codes . You can hold HASH of multiple files in MEMORY. And use threads to compare your new File's HASH concurrently .. Won't that help :) ? [And when you finish with one HASH set , you load others from a database]

Comment: You could use the BINARY_CHECKSUM(). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx . Storing /caching integer values are most of the time going to be faster than storing/caching the whole row. You can do a checksum along with the identity and for the modified partitions, you can do the select or the modifications you would like.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally if you are playing with a large number of data then you have to make sure that you do not run out of resources while processing your data. However you just need to find a reasonable way to increase the utilization of your resources.

I would definitely go with database because that is the best known way to query and storing of the data in most optimal way. You didn't mention what exactly your application does, so I can just give you general opinions about how I would do in such scenario;

1. If data size of your database is really big as you say in billions and if you data being read for analytic or reporting purposes you better find a data mining technique like cubes etc. This would help you to structure your data in a way to reduce the query time.
2. If above is not an option find a way to horizontally or vertically partitioning your data, well it also depends upon how you actually retrieving the data and how you can really group them together.
3. Find a way to query a group of rows (e.g. where pk in (1,2,3,4,...,100) instead querying each row at time as you mentioned earlier, grouping may increase the query response in exponential way.
4. Its best to find a primary key within data itself so that your data will be sorted in order of your primary key physically and you will know your primary key before even inserting it. However if you are not querying with primary key then better to place reason-able indexes to increase query response time.
5. Keep the database connection open for life of your application and reconnect only if dropped. and use connection pool if multiple connections to database is expected.